# Why the output is the same for every input value except null in python?

Tags: python, boolean

`bool(input("Enter input :"))`

when the input is null, this will output False.

But when we give any value it gives out True.

Why is that?

Comment: Because any non-empty string is True-like as per the boolean rules Python uses...

Comment: Might be worth reading [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth). Pythons bool function lets you convert any Python value into a Boolean one. Dependent on their truthy value

Comment: This question is not a duplicate.

Comment: @lahiruhashan Can you elaborate on why it's not a duplicate of the suggested question? It looks very similar to me.